# D - Part in PID doesn't impact steady state error?

Tags: control-theory

Why does the D-part in a PID controller not do any impact on the steady state error. I mean if tries to resist changes, should it not then make it stay at wanted configuration?

Answer (score 0):

A [PID controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) generates a control input

$$u(t) = u_\text{P}(t)+u_\text{I}(t)+u_\text{D}(t).$$

The contributions of each of the terms can be written explicitly by using the error $e$.

$$=k_\text{P}e(t)+k_\text{I}\int_{\tau=t_0}^{t}e(\tau)~d\tau + k_\text{D}\dfrac{d}{dt}e(t).$$

Now, we assume that our system is in a state with constant error $e(t) = \text{const}$. What will happen to the different components? It is clear that the derivative term $k_\text{D}\dot{e}(t)$ will vanish. Only the proportional and the integral terms will provide a non-zero term for the total control input. The proportional term will not increase its action even if we have a remaining constant error. The integral term will accumulate errors and increase its action. Hence, only the integral term will increase its action for a steady state error. Note, that the integral term might lead to a phenomenon called [integrator windup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_windup) if the control input is saturated.

Answer (score -2):

If the steady state error is nonzero but settles down then the derivative is zero hence no correction. That's why there is always, though small, integral action added in the controller. Such that when it builds up, the system is forced to return to the designated reference.

Comment: Integral action is not always added, PD- (and for that matter, just P-) controllers are very frequently used. Not only is an I component often unnecessary for practical reasons, if your system has an integrator, it is not needed as the system will converge itself, as long as it is regulated.

Comment: @lifesayko Not quite, you cannot have integral action with your own system pole at zero. Take a simple mass and apply any input with or without regulation (see also Brockett's condition hence that is simply wrong). Integral action is not equal to PID controllers I coefficient. Please read carefully. This is much more general than PIDs. I didn't mention PID at all. Your answer is simply a copy of mine.

Comment: My main gripe is the statement of "there is always integral action added", which is simply not the case and misleading. Otherwise, yes, your answer already includes most of mine. I added my answer mainly because I found that your answer is not very clear and not well-suited to the level of the question.

Comment: @lifesayko If you are doing your job as a control engineer properly, you should include integral action, your professor might disagree.